# Aero in VB running windows xp

Tags: .net, vb.net, aero

Is it possible to draw WPF elements in Aero style, running on Windows XP? Also can you change the window style to look like Aero? BTW I found a reference PresentationFramework.Aero, is it something to do with this?

Comment: WinXP does not have aero. You would need to take complete control of all the drawing; no simple 'style change' can do it.

Comment: @AnrewBarber Then the only possible solution is to restyle everything by myself with WPF Styles?

Comment: There may be hope yet: http://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/11/02/getting-aero-theme-with-wpf-on-windows-xp/)

Comment: @aligray This is just what I need, but is there a way to change the title bar and borders of the window?

Comment: It could be fiddly, but this post might help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2008/09/08/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised the comments above were not compiled in an actual answer...

Windows XP does not natively have the "Aero" theme or the glass effect, as you probably know, so there is no built in support for it. The only way to achieve it would be through drawing it yourself.

A Google of "aero effects on windows xp" reveals that there are a number of programs, both commercial and freeware, that duplicate the Aero Glass effect on XP, however I'm not sure that will be the best option for your software.

The links aligray gave will probably help you a lot. However, all the same, duplicating the Aero Glass effect will be iffy on and XP system, due to both hardware and software limitations.